# an expression for "falling into mud is Ok, but staying in it isn't"

Tags: expressions

I was looking for an expression which would convey the same meaning as this sentence:

> "falling into mud is Ok, but staying in it isn't"

this is actually a translation of one of the expressions that we have here. thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps some variant indicating the important thing is *not the hand you're dealt, but how you play it.*

Comment: @Davo Maybe. But I'm getting more of a "mistakes are okay, as long as you learn from them." kind of vibe, versus your "make the best of a bad situation" offer. Something closer to "If at first you don't succeed, try and try again" or "When the going gets tough, the tough get going."

Comment: 'Down but not out' http://language.chinadaily.com.cn/columnist/2008-01/25/content_6421124.htm

Comment: We all seem to be stuck in the soft & pungent on this one...

Answer (score 2):

Nelson Mandela once said:

> The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising
>   every time we fall.

and Jack Penn:

> One of the secrets of life is to make stepping stones out of stumbling
>   blocks.

{[WiseOldSayings.com](http://www.wiseoldsayings.com/overcoming-obstacles-quotes/)}

and Frank Sinatra tells us to ' ... Pick yourself up, Dust yourself down, Start all over again.' (Kern & Fields)

Comment: Failure isn't the opposite of success, It is part of success.

Comment: 'If a man waited till he could do a thing perfectly, he would never do anything at all' Preface to _Vogel's Organic Chemistry_.

Comment: I knew I should have read Vogel more carefully. But it sounds like an updated Newman quote.